# Update Gtk.Label when active item in Gtk.ComboBox is changed

Tags: gtk, vala

I want to update the labels when the active item in a Gtk.ComboBox is changed.

This is how I create the combo boxes

```
public class Epoch.CitiesChooser : Gtk.Grid {
    string[] cities = {"Guwahati", "Paris", "London", "New York"};
    
    public Gtk.ComboBox city1box;
    public Gtk.ComboBox city2box;
    public Gtk.ComboBox city3box;
    public Gtk.ComboBox city4box;
    
    enum Column {
        CITY
    }
    
    construct {
        var liststore = new Gtk.ListStore (1, typeof (string));
        
        for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            Gtk.TreeIter iter;
            liststore.append (out iter);
            liststore.set (iter, Column.CITY, cities[i]);
        }
        
        city1box = new Gtk.ComboBox.with_model (liststore);
        var cell1 = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();
        city1box.pack_start (cell1, false);
        city1box.set_attributes (cell1, "text", Column.CITY);
            
        city1box.set_active (0);
        
        var city2box = new Gtk.ComboBox.with_model (liststore);
        var cell2 = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();
        city2box.pack_start (cell2, false);
        city2box.set_attributes (cell2, "text", Column.CITY);
        
        city2box.set_active (1);
        
        var city3box = new Gtk.ComboBox.with_model (liststore);
        var cell3 = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();
        city3box.pack_start (cell3, false);
        city3box.set_attributes (cell3, "text", Column.CITY);
        
        city3box.set_active (2);
        
        var city4box = new Gtk.ComboBox.with_model (liststore);
        var cell4 = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();
        city4box.pack_start (cell4, false);
        city4box.set_attributes (cell4, "text", Column.CITY);
        
        city4box.set_active (3);
        
        this.attach (city1box, 0, 0);
        this.attach (city2box, 0, 1);
        this.attach (city3box, 0, 2);
        this.attach (city4box, 0, 3);   
    }
}
```

And this is how I create the labels and try to update them:

```
public class Epoch.LabelsGrid : Object {
    public Gtk.Label face1_label;
    public Gtk.Label face2_label;
    public Gtk.Label face3_label;
    public Gtk.Label face4_label;
    
    // public Epoch.CitiesChooser cities_chooser;
    
    construct {
        face1_label = new Gtk.Label ("");
        face1_label.set_markup ("<span font_desc='Inter 14'><b>Guwahati</b></span>");
        face1_label.halign = Gtk.Align.CENTER;
        face1_label.hexpand = true;
        face1_label.margin_top = 6;
        face1_label.set_ellipsize (END);
        face1_label.set_max_width_chars (12);
        
        face2_label = new Gtk.Label ("");
        face2_label.set_markup ("<span font_desc='Inter 14'><b>Paris</b></span>");
        face2_label.halign = Gtk.Align.CENTER;
        face2_label.hexpand = true;
        face2_label.margin_top = 6;
        face2_label.set_ellipsize (END);
        face2_label.set_max_width_chars (12);
        
        face3_label = new Gtk.Label ("");
        face3_label.set_markup ("<span font_desc='Inter 14'><b>London</b></span>");
        face3_label.halign = Gtk.Align.CENTER;
        face3_label.hexpand = true;
        face3_label.margin_top = 6;
        face3_label.set_ellipsize (END);
        face3_label.set_max_width_chars (12);
        
        face4_label = new Gtk.Label ("");
        face4_label.set_markup ("<span font_desc='Inter 14'><b>New York</b></span>");
        face4_label.halign = Gtk.Align.CENTER;
        face4_label.hexpand = true;
        face4_label.margin_top = 6;
        face4_label.set_ellipsize (END);
        face4_label.set_max_width_chars (12);
        
        var cities_chooser = new Epoch.CitiesChooser ();
        
        cities_chooser.city1box.changed.connect (() => {
            face1_label.set_markup ("<span font_desc='Inter 14'><b>Paris</b></span>");
            stdout.printf ("Signal is working correctly");
        });
    }
}
```

The application compiles without any error but the labels are not updated when the active item in the combobox (city1box) is changed.

Can anyone tell me how to correctly update the labels?

I think is has something to do with the signal

Comment: This is not C code. Please review your tags.

Comment: Oh, I added the c tag because vala converts to c.

Answer (score 0):

Which CitiesChooser are you changing the combobox of? It can't be the same CitiesChooser you're connecting to, because that one is a local variable and you never do anything with it. It will be deleted when it goes out of scope.

You need to connect to the signal of the CitiesChooser that is in your UI.

Comment: Do you mean that I should connect to the signal of the CitiesChooser in the CitiesChooser file itself?

Comment: I tried doing that, and the message "Signal is working correctly" was printed. But the label was not updated and the terminal was showing `Segmentation fault`

Comment: You need to connect to the CitiesChooser that is in your UI, wherever that is.

Comment: I did to that and its resulting in Segmentation fault

Comment: As you have mentioned in your anseer, I initiale the face1_label as a variable in the CitiesChooser class and maybe that is why, it gets deleted as it is not in scope.